# How to use a variable inside activerecord query in yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How do I convert the following to active record style in yii2?

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE created_at >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

What I have tried:

```
switch ($period) {
        case 'y':
            $p = "12 month";
            break;
        case 'm':
            $p = "1 month";
            break;
        case 'w':
            $p = "7 days";
            break;
        case 'd':
            $p = "1 days";
            break;
}

Customers::find()
  ->where('>=', 'created_at', (CURDATE() - INTERVAL $p))
  ->orderBy('id DESC');
```

But I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$p' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii2 has an `Expression` class to help with those kinds of things ([doc here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html)).

In your case, it'd look something like:

```
Customers::find()
    ->where(['>=', 'created_at', new \yii\db\Expression('(CURDATE() - INTERVAL ' . $p . ')'))
    ->orderBy('id DESC');
```

Answer (score 4):

insted of pass the string
you could pass the $p as a param

```
  Customers::find()
    ->where( 'created_at >=(CURDATE() - INTERVAL :p' ), [':p'=>$p])
    ->orderBy('id DESC');
```